# Ruby gem for audit request params

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any ruby gem available for getting request object values? I need to save particular values from request object to rails db. Like the values below

- request.headers['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
- request.headers['QUERY_STRING']
- request.headers['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH']
- request.remote_ip
- request.remote_addr

I need to save these values for a particular page loaded everytime in rails db. I know we can directly get from request object. But doing via gem may simplify my work.

Comment: I don't think it's something that requires a gem, it would be a few lines of code in a before filter.

Comment: but a sophisticated gem can give several stats instead of we writing it.